# Array de objetos no ajax com mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax

Eu tenho uma função que pega as variaveis de uma lista, cria os objetos, e insere em uma lista de objetos. Mas preciso passar essa lista para o controlador mvc;

## Função jquery

```
$(function() {
jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;
$("#saveDiffer").on('click',
    function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        var count = 0;
        var differs = [];
        $('.differ').each(function() {
            var nome = $(this).children('input').val();
            var tipo = $(this).find('li.active').find('span').text();
            var differ = {
                Nome: nome,
                Tipo: tipo
            };
            differs.push(differ);

        });
        console.log(differs);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/Upload/SaveDiffer',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            data: JSON.stringify(differs),
            contentType: 'application/JSON; charset=utf-8',
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function(data) {
                console.log(data)
            }

        });

    });
});
```

---

## Controller

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SaveDiffer(List<AtividadeJsonModel> differs)
    {
        // Código aqui
        return null;
    }
```

---

## Modelo

```
public class AtividadeJsonModel
    {
        public string Nome { get; set; }
        public string Tipo { get; set; }
    }
```

---

## Edit

Eu tentei usar o `[FromBody]` no controller, como algumas resposta sugerem, mas sem sucesso, ele recebe um null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu consegui fazer funcionar usando `[FromBody]` e linkando com outro modelo para fazer a array.

> **Importante**: o '`Modelos`' deve bater com o nome da array dentro do model

---

> O JSON ficaria assim `{"Modelos":[{"nome":"Teste Ausencia","tipo":"Ausencia"},{"nome":"Teste Extra","tipo":"Extra"}]}`

## Post:

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: '/Upload/SaveDiffer',
   dataType: 'JSON',
   data: JSON.stringify({ 'Modelos': differs }),
   contentType: 'application/JSON; charset=utf-8',
   success: function(data){
      console.log(data);
   },
   error: function(data) {
      console.log(data)
   }
});
```

## Os modelos:

```
public class AtividadeJsonModel
{
    public Modelo[] Modelos { get; set; }
}
public class Modelo
{
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Tipo { get; set; }
}
```

## E o controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public void SaveDiffer([FromBody]AtividadeJsonModel differ)
    {
        insira o código aqui;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Invés disso:

```
data: JSON.stringify(differs),
```

Tente assim:

```
data: JSON.stringify({ 'differs': differs}),
```

Exemplo:

```
var cores = [
    { id: 1, color: 'yellow' },
    { id: 2, color: 'blue' },
    { id: 3, color: 'red' }
];

JSON.stringify(cores);

// Retorno: "[{"id":1,"color":"yellow"},{"id":2,"color":"blue"},{"id":3,"color":"red"}]"

JSON.stringify({ 'cores': cores });

// Retorno: "{"cores":[{"id":1,"color":"yellow"},{"id":2,"color":"blue"},{"id":3,"color":"red"}]}"
```

Comment: Mesmo assim o differs no controller esta com count 0